# Anyon Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, quantum-spin, spin-statistics, anyons

The discussion of 2D quantum mechanics of two identical particles may be started [(as written in the following article)](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217751X88001181) with  Lagrangian

> $$ L_s = \frac{\theta}{\pi} \dot{\phi} $$
>   where $\phi$ is the relative angle between two particles and $\theta$ a numerical parameter.

The question is how should I think of this Lagrangian? The only analogy that comes to mind is also linear to velocity term $\frac{q}{c} \vec{v}\cdot\vec{A}$ of patricle in a field, but that does not give me a proper understanding of anyon Lagrangian.

Comment: In article this Lagrangian term is called "statistical interaction"